# Factoring Polynomials with Complex Numbers

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, factoring

I have this polynomial that I am trying to simplify in the form $(1-\alpha_1B)(1-\alpha_2B)$

The polynomial is

> $(1 - 1.1x + 0.3x^2)$

I know I need to use complex numbers, but I'm not quite sure how.

I know that there are roots at $x = 1.67$ and $x = 2$, but I was hoping to represent it in the form above $(1-\alpha_1B)(1-\alpha_2B)$

Comment: Hint 1: Compute the solutions of $1-1.1x+0.3x^2=0$.
Hint 2: You won't need complex numbers.

Comment: I know that there are two real roots, but is there any way I can get it in the form $(1-\alpha_1x)(1-\alpha_2x)$?

Comment: If $x_1,x_2$ are the real roots, then $(x_1-x)(x_2-x)=(1-x/x_1)(1-x/x_2)x_1x_2$.

Comment: $(1-x/(5/3))(1-x/2).$